# Kotlin Spring optional RequestBody map empty string to null

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, serialization, jackson

Recently I did a change to an **API** which at first should've been backwards compatible, but due to the client my endpoint started responding **400 Bad Request**, what I did is added optional RequestBody to **PUT** endpoint which shouldn't have cause any issues since it's optional, but client send empty string value which can't be deserialized into object and Jackson fails to deserialize.

My dto object:

```
data class TestRequest(@field:Future val expiresDatetime: Instant? )
```

Endpoint definition:

```
@PutMapping("/{testId}/revoke")
fun revoke(
@PathVariable testId: String,
@Valid
@RequestBody(required = false)
request: TestRequest? = null,
): TestRevokeResponse =
testService.revoke(testId, request)
```

Upon debugging what is being sent to the endpoint I noticed these headers:
`Content-Type: application/json content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 content-length: 2`

And payload being: `""`

Is there a way of defaulting for empty string to null without writing custom deserializer?

I've tried writting my own deserializer but it seems as an overhead for such a case to create deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of defaulting for empty string to null without writing
> custom deserializer?

Yes, you can enable the [`ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) deserialization feature to allow JSON empty String value ("") to be bound as `null` for POJOs and other structured values (Maps, Collections):

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
val testRequest = mapper1.readValue<TestRequest>(request)
```

If the change is limited to just one endpoint like you described you can create inside the bound controller a new `ObjectMapper` mapper with the enabled feature to avoid unknown side effects in other parts of your application and convert the `RequestBody` value to a `string` value, then passing the string value to the local mapper.